# How do I trigger capacitive touch screen electronically (without hands)?

Tags: switches, remote-control, capacitive, touchscreen, smartphones

I would like to trigger a "touch" or "touches" to a smartphone screen electronically without actually touching the screen with my finger using a remote control somehow.

The idea would be that every time I would press the remote control, it would trigger a momentary "touch" to the screen.

Is there a way to do this? If so, can someone offer a basic schematic for how something like this would be wired along with a list of suggested components?

My question was flagged as a possible duplicate but I checked the other post and so far, a solid answer hasn’t reached quite yet.

Thanks!

Comment: The post you’re referencing doesn’t quite answer my question

Comment: a finger is a dielectric insulator with mainly water based fluids with high Dk=80 when the air gap is closed by touch. so how to make a sensor that couples signals to adjacent pixels by capacitance or some matrix switches of fine concentric circular capacitors that can be electrically joined to increase capacitance instead of all in series, put all in parallel? Analog Switch matrix?  1st find the sensitivity in surface capacitance  per sq mm or sq cm to trigger screen in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbixDO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The GND should be a return path, allowing the capacitors in the screen to detect a return path, similar to the one created by you touching the screen.
This could not work if the leakage current exceeds the detection threshold of the capacitive screen, but it's worth a shot.